# SCD in BIDS 2016 SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, scd, scd2

I am trying to achieve Type 2 SCD using SCD transformation. When I update something in the source, instead of updating that row alone, SCD transformation is updating and inserting all the rows.

Example, soruce has 50 rows and destination has same 50 rows after first run.now I updated row 1 in source and ran the package, then all the rows got inserted again instead of updating that single row.

Any idea why ??

Comment: You'd expect one row to get updated with an insert, that's what Type 2 does, but not all of them. It looks like the transformation is thinking the rows are all new, which means that the comparison columns you're using aren't matching for some reason. No time for a full answer, hopefully that's enough of a starting point.

Comment: You need to show us more on how you have it configured: the settings, the things you have connected as output, etc.